# Queue messages in android for sending when device is online

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, message-queue

What is the best way to queue e.g chat messages intended to be sent to the server until when the device is back online.

Scenario:

1) User Sends Message (No Internet Connection or connection timeout)

2) Message should be sent when there is an internet connection.

Also,
If a message hasn't been delivered and in the process device is turned off
When the device is turned up, undelivered messages should be sent to the server.

This is what i thought of:

i: save undelivered messages in the device DB with a flag e.g undelivered

ii: Keep retrying to send the messages with undelivered flag

iii: listen for BOOT_COMPLETED such that when the device turns up, i continue the  process

...

Comment: **"Keep retrying to send the messages with undelivered flag"** : You don't need to keep trying periodically. Just use a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for when a network / Internet connection is available. Search Stack Overflow for something like "how to detect network available" or "how to detect internet available". Use an `IntentService` to handle all sending of messages.

Comment: @Squonk thanks for the reply... This gave me a path way to the solution.. thanks... i will implement it has you said, and yeah i found out nice ways of detecting internet connection, i guess i'm good to go

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) to handle all of your required tasks.